# MySQL PDO how to bind params for IN()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP, MySQL and PDO.

```
$ids = '1,2,3';
```

I have a query like this which works:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN($ids)
```

This returns 3 rows as expected

If I use:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE id IN(:ids)

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($q);
$params = array('ids' => $ids);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

It only returns 1 row.

How can I bind the ids?

According to https://phpdelusions.net/pdo I should use:

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in)";
```

but how can I put my ids of 1,2,3 which are stored in $ids into $arr = [1,2,3] because if I write

```
 $arr = [$ids]
```

it's basically writing

```
 $arr = ['1,2,3']
```

instead of

```
$arr = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: I don't think you can with IN() contents.

Comment: Have a look at [this site](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), search the page for `IN()` for an example.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I see the solution there but I'm faced with a new problem: See my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
$ids = '1,2,3';
```

Explode the $ids string into an array:

```
$ids_array = explode(',', $ids);
```

This gives:

```
$ids_array[] = 1;
$ids_array[] = 2;
$ids_array[] = 3;
```

Create a comma-delimited string of question marks. The number of question marks matches the number of array values

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($ids_array) - 1) . '?';
```

This produces a string that looks like:

```
?,?,?
```

Put that string into the sql

```
$q = "SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE id IN($in) ";


$stmt = $this->db->prepare($q);
```

Execute the query, passing the array as a parameter

```
$stmt->execute($ids_array);
```